# Android emulator with Camera API

Tags: android, camera

I am using camera API to build a custom camera. I used emulator to test my application,but it shows me only a white screen on camera.open(). Is there a chance that it is my code's fault or the emulator's?

Comment: did u enable camera support in emulator

Comment: which api level you are using if u use api level >4.0 then it's work

Comment: Ok, I am using api 2.2

Answer (score 1):

You are getting black screen because you are not calling Camera intent properly or you have done `startActivity()` without any target..

Please refer **[this sample code for ref](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)**..

Comment: Can you please refer to this?
http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/working-with-camera-on-android-sdk/

Comment: I cant see any thing in the place of camera,except a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please Take a notice of this.There have nothing to do with code unless you see a log cat.Second you need really good emulator to test in a case to get away of failure.Here is the link of good emulator you try it and if you see no errors in log cat it means your good to go with your code.Visit https://www.genymotion.com
For My opinion there is no powerful emulator than genymotion gives.